# Delete the user pool added by AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I'm developing a React Native app and using AWS Amplify with Amazon Cognito for authentication. I've added the authentication for the app using Amplify CLI (`amplify add auth`). The problem is I need to add/remove the required attributes for the sign up, but those cannot be changed after the user pool is created.

My question is how can I delete the currently added user pool using the CLI, and making sure that the changes are reflected in `aws-exports.js`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I figured it out. As mentioned [here](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/2677), it's not in `amplify-cli` docs, but you can remove a single category (in this case `auth`) like this:

```
amplify remove <category>
```

So, in this case, it would be

```
amplify remove auth
```

And, then

```
amplify push
```

Answer (score 1):

```
aws cognito-idp delete-user-pool --user-pool-id youruserpoolid
```

Comment: Do I need to do `amplify pull` after this?

Comment: You may be able to create a new user pool manually and then link it to your Amplify like this outlines https://medium.com/@danielcender/use-a-custom-cognito-user-pool-with-aws-appsync-3d0c82f3010b . I'm not too sure they support an out of the box way of switching user pools

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60098978/how-to-change-aws-cognito-user-pools-in-an-angular-app-to-another-user-pool-usi?rq=1